# unexpected end of subtree using findAll

Tags: java, grails, findall

I'm working with my grails project, and want to retrieve all the CompanyProfileOtherDetails intance that has specific activity types.

```
def getInstance

getInstance = CompanyProfileOtherDetails.findAll('from CompanyProfileOtherDetails as od where od.activityType in(:activityTypes)', [activityTypes: ActivityType.findAllByName(['Distribution', 'Dealer'])])
```

I expect the outpul of CompanyProfileOtherDetails instances but the actual output is

```
unexpected end of subtree [from ph.gov.doe.core.stakeholder.CompanyProfileOtherDetails as od where od.activityType in()]
```

Here's the CompanyProfileOtherDetails domain class

```
package ph.gov.doe.core.stakeholder

import ph.gov.doe.core.product.ProductType
import ph.gov.doe.core.requirement.ActivityType
import ph.gov.doe.core.product.SubproductType

/**
 * This class represents a company profile's other details
 */
class CompanyProfileOtherDetails {

/** Defines a many-to-one relationship with <code>Company Profile</code> class. */
static belongsTo = [companyProfile: CompanyProfile]
/** COC number of the Company Profile */
String cocNumber

/** Defines a many-to-many relationship with <code>Activity Type and Product Type</code> class. */
static hasMany = [activityType: ActivityType, productType: ProductType, subproductTypes: SubproductType]

/** Defines validation rules, schema generation and CRUD generation meta data. */   
static constraints = {
    cocNumber nullable: true, unique: false, blank: true, size: 5..50, matches: /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/\\]+$/
    activityType nullable: true , blank: true 
    productType nullable: true , blank: true
    subproductTypes nullable: true , blank: true
}

/** Defines the way class <code>CompanyProfileOtherDetails</code>'s properties are mapped to the database. */
static mapping = {
    table 'company_profile_details'
    companyProfile column: 'company_profile_id'
    // tradeName column :'trade_name'
    // cocNumber column : 'coc_number'
}
}
```

And here's the Activity Type

```
package ph.gov.doe.core.requirement
import ph.gov.doe.core.acl.Division
/**
 * This class represents an activity type.
 */
class ActivityType implements Serializable {

    String name
    String description
    /** Flag that tells if this activity type is still active. */
    boolean active = true
    /** Division that sets the activity type */
    Division division

    /** Defines validation rules, schema generation and CRUD generation meta data. */
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 2..150, matches: "[A-Za-z0-9-. _Ññ,]+", unique: true
        description nullable: false, blank: false, size: 2..255, matches: /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9\Ñ\ñ].*)([a-zA-Z0-9\Ñ\ñ\.\, \_\-\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\:\;\?\/\\\<\>\"\'])+$/
        division nullable: false, blank: false
    }

    /**  Defines the way class <code>ActivityType</code>'s properties are mapped to the database. */
    static mapping = {
        table 'activity_type'
        name name: 'name'
        active name: 'is_active'
        description name: 'description'
        division name: 'oimb_division_id'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

should add **inList** in dynamic finder

```
ActivityType.findAllByNameInList(['Distribution', 'Dealer'])
```

and i suggest u can try use dynamic finder ,like code below

```
        def CompanyProfileOtherDetailsInstanceList = CompanyProfileOtherDetails.createCriteria().list(){
            or {
                ActivityType.findAllByNameInList(['Distribution', 'Dealer']).id.each {id ->
                    ActivityType {
                        idEq(id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

(p.s. IL means InstanceList)

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, but it has an error says that "Message: No value specified for parameter 1".

Comment: can i see ur grails.domain class CompanyProfileOtherDetails and ActivityType

Comment: i find a likely soluction here  , i can't try(my project DB didn't create realaction ) i ha sample code above (update in post)
http://ryanalberts.com/92/grails-findby-for-hasmany-relationship/